# how to show associativity of multiplication for not just 3 operands but for n operands

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, axioms

ie Id like to show
a(bc)=(ab)c
but for any n operands
eg
abcdefg=gfdcabe etc

I can see this is very intuitive that this should be true for all n operands, but as a logical exercise I would like to see how this is formally shown.. Im interested in the reasoning.. and how to arrive at such things.

It seems there are infinite possible operands, so do we need to work backwards and use the inverse (division)?

thanks.

Comment: you use induction.

Comment: But how does the induction step prove/show it for more than 3 operands? (its still only using 3 operands not 4 or more). How can we show, using (ab)c = a(bc)  that abcd=adbc ? (but not just for that specific eg but for all possible (n) operands) ?

Comment: I think you are mixing up associativity (where the order of operands remains the same - you are rearranging brackets) and commutativity (where the reordering is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associativity of a binary operation means that it naturally extends to $n$-ary operations for all $n=3,4,5,6,..$, uniquely in the sense that reordering brackets  (i.e. the order of evaluation of the partial products) doesn't change the result (and it **doesn't even change the order** of members). So that we can uniquely define terms like $abcdefg$, which is, among many other possible brackettings,  $=(abc(de)f)g$.

To prove this, you can use induction on $n$.

On the other hand, *commutativity* means that $ab=ba$ for all pairs of elements. In the example 'to show $abcdefg=gfdcabe$' you *implicitly* used that the operation is associative (because of the lack of any brackets, though originally product is said to be binary operation), and over that, the commutativity condition is needed to prove this.

Comment: Beautifully simple answer... thank you. My "flash of insight" came when you showed this: "(and it doesn't even change the order of members)"... "abcdefg, which is, among many other possible brackettings, =(abc(de)f)g". Clear as day now. ;) Thanks again